# Why does it execute two 'else if' statements?

Tags: c, xcode

I've taken a piece of the larger code to bring emphasis. The code works properly (good output), but i have a question about it. In the code below, why does it appear that two 'else if' statements are being executed? I learned that the difference between having a series of 'if' statements versus 'else if' was that all 'if' statements are executed, but that when using a series of 'else if' statements, the moment one gets executed, the program does not continue on that thread. It appears that typing 1 1 2 2 executes both codes below, but wouldn't it only execute the first 'else if' statement'? If so, why then is there an output of ixlarge = 4 ?

```
          else if (x3 >= x4 && x3 >= x2 && x3 >= x1)
              xlarge = x3;
          else if(x4 >= x3 && x4 >= x2 && x4 >= x1)
              xlarge = x4;
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int x1, x2, x3, x4;
    int xlarge, xsmall, ixlarge, ixsmall;

    while( 1 )
    {
        printf( "enter x1, x2, x3, x4:\n" );
        scanf( "%d%d%d%d", &x1, &x2, &x3, &x4 );

          xlarge = -1;
          xsmall = -1;
          if(x1 >= x2 && x1 >= x3 && x1 >= x4 )
              xlarge = x1;
          else if((x2 >= x3 && x2 >= x4 && x2 >= x1))
              xlarge = x2;
          else if (x3 >= x4 && x3 >= x2 && x3 >= x1)
              xlarge = x3;
          else if(x4 >= x3 && x4 >= x2 && x4 >= x1)
              xlarge = x4;

        printf("%d",xlarge);

          if(x1 == xlarge)
              ixlarge = 1;
          if(x2 == xlarge)
              ixlarge = 2;
          if(x3 == xlarge)
              ixlarge = 3;
          if(x4 == xlarge)
              ixlarge = 4;
        printf("%d",ixlarge);
         /*if(x3 == xlarge && x4 == xlarge)
             ixlarge = 4;*/


          if(x1 <= x2 && x1 <= x3 && x1 <= x4 )
              xsmall = x1;
          else if((x2 <= x3 && x2 <= x4 && x2 <= x1))
              xsmall = x2;
          else if (x3 <= x4 && x3 <= x2 && x3 <= x1)
              xsmall = x3;
          else if(x4 <= x3 && x4 <= x2 && x4 <= x1)
              xsmall = x4;

          
        
          if(x1 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;
          if(x2 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 2;
          if(x3 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 3;
          if(x4 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 4;
          if(x3 == xsmall && x4 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 3;
          if(x2 == xsmall && x1 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;
          if(x1 == xsmall && x3 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;
          if(x1 == xsmall && x4 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;
          if(x2 == xsmall && x3 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 2;
          if(x2 == xsmall && x4 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 2;
          if(x1 == xsmall && x3 == xsmall && x2 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;
          if(x1 == xsmall && x4 == xsmall && x2 == xsmall)
              ixsmall = 1;

        printf( "largest = %4d at position %d, ", xlarge, ixlarge );
        printf( "smallest = %4d at position %d\n", xsmall, ixsmall );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, to see what *really* happens?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong section of code.  What you've highlighted will set `xlarge = x3` namely `xlarge = 2` as it should.  But your question is about how `ixlarge` is set.  Look at the section of code starting with `if(x1 == xlarge)` and notice that there are *no* `else` blocks there.  Also note that since `x3` and `x4` have the same value, the expressions `x3 == xlarge` and `x4 == xlarge` are both true.

Comment: It's not the `else if`. It's the `if` statements that set `ixlarge` to 3 and then to 4. For easy debugging, put a `printf` inside of every `if`, `else if`, and `else` to see the program flow.

Comment: By the way, I hope this very long and tedious code will be good motivation to learn about loops.

Comment: And I reiterate my point about using a debugger... If you have used a debugger to step through the code, you would probably have found out the problem in less time than it took to write the question itself. Being able to debug ones own code is a *crucial* and *mandatory* knowledge for any programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an input of "1 1 2 2", both `x3` and `x4` have a value of 2, so this block:

```
      else if (x3 >= x4 && x3 >= x2 && x3 >= x1)
          xlarge = x3;
```

Is the one that is executed, although if the other was executed `xlarge` would still have the same value.  The part that makes indicates that `x4` is the largest is this:

```
      if(x3 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 3;
      if(x4 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 4;
```

Because `x3` and `x4` have the same value, both of these `if` blocks will execute, leaving `ixlarge` with a value of 4.

You can fix this by changing this set of `if` statements:

```
      if(x1 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 1;
      if(x2 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 2;
      if(x3 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 3;
      if(x4 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 4;
```

To `if`/`else`:

```
      if(x1 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 1;
      else if(x2 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 2;
      else if(x3 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 3;
      else if(x4 == xlarge)
          ixlarge = 4;
```

And perform a similar change when setting `ixsmall`.

On a side node, your code can be made **much** simpler and less error-prone if you used an array and loops instead of 4 separate variables.

Comment: how does x4 get assigned xlarge? it only executed the first 'if else' you have shown and therefore only x3 got assigned to xlarge. How then could you run the two if statements? The program is blind to the second if statement you have shown since x4 never got assigned xlarge. Maybe I'm thinking of it too narrowly as in there needs to be an assigned value otherwise where is it coming from? Looks to be like its coming from thin air.

Comment: @JoshMcCloud  `x4` isn't getting assigned to `xlarge`, `x3` is.  However, both `x3` and `x4` have the same value.  Therefore, both `x3 == xlarge` is true and `x4 == xlarge` is true.  The former sets `ixlarge` to 3, then the latter sets it again to 4.

Comment: How does it know it has the same value? Is it an automatic thing that we can't see?

Comment: @JoshMcCloud Because you entered the value 2 for both.  So after the initial if/else block, `x3`, `x4`, and `xlarge` all have the value 2.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for some kind of concrete or tangible visibility code. But it seems that what you are telling me is an invisible and automatic thing . Because x3 has a 2, that automatically links it to x4 due to its value of 2 as well

Comment: @JoshMcCloud  You enter the values 1, 1, 2, 2, for `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, and `x4` respectively.  In the first if/else block, the condition `(x3 >= x4 && x3 >= x2 && x3 >= x1)` is true, so the assignment `xlarge = x3;` occurs.  Now `xlarge` contains the value 2.  Then you have a series of `if` statements.  `if (x1 == xlarge)` is false.  `if (x2 == xlarge)` is false.  `if (x3 == xlarge)` is true so `ixlarge = 3` occurs.  Then `if (x4 == xlarge)` is true so `ixlarge = 4` occurs, overwriting the value of 3 that `ixlarge` previously had.

Comment: I used the debugger and it indeed does what you say it does, but still no clue as to  how xlarge and x4 were tied together.  You're saying because x3 and x4 have the same value. Alright, but then that means its an automatic tying of x4 to xlarge as no visible code does it. Like its an innate thing.

Comment: @JoshMcCloud  There's no "automatic tying"  You set `x3` to 2 and you set `x4` to 2.  Then `xlarge` gets set to the value of `x3`, which is 2.  So now `x3` is 2, `x4` is 2, and `xlarge` is 2.

Comment: @JoshMcCloud The only reason you think `xlarge` is linked to `x4` is because you're setting `ixlarge` incorrectly.